# Ionic iOS Cordova Push Token

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm currently working on an Ionic project and using Cordova Push plugin for notifications. Currently the device is able to register a device token for GCM Android but it isn't apple to get a token for the Apple Iphone.

The way it works is the token would be sent to an API server where it will handle notification using the tokens.

I've checked the `Push Notifications` to `ON` in Xcode for Push Notifications entitlement, added cordova push, activated the push notifications on the `Apple Developer` which involved downloading the certificate from Apple Developer Console and applying it to the Keychain Access.

Am I missing any steps?

My code looks like:

```
cordovaPush.register(config).then(function(result) {
    console.log('###### RESPONSE #######')
    console.log(result);
}, function(err) {
    console.log(err);
});

$rootScope.$on('$cordovaPush:notificationReceived', function(event, notification) {
    console.log(notification);
});
```

Note: I've switched to PhoneGap Push Plugin. This might've solved the problem (haven't tested yet).

Anyone solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Using PhoneGap Push Plugin solves this all. It seemed to be the library that was't working with the new iOS.